# Surprising tutorial behavior when using model->SetLinearVel. Also, where can I learn more?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I've got questions about behavior seen in the model-plugin tutorial:

http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=plugins_model&cat=write_plugin

When I compile and run it the box slides along the ground for a bit then starts to turn over.  Why does this happen?  Is the ground bumpy or something?  It appears smooth.

The behavior is also surprising because the plugin uses SetLinearVel() so I thought that would constrain the linear velocity of the box's center of mass but when it starts to flip over the z-component of velocity must be non-zero.  Any comments about this discrepancy?

Finally, can you tell me where I can learn about what functions are available for links and models so that I can learn to write plugins controlling multi-link bodies?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/12338/surprising-tutorial-behavior-when-using-model-%3Esetlinearvel.--also,-where-can-i-learn-more?/) by [raequin](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2401/raequin/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 165 on 2016-01-14

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [raequin](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2401/raequin/) on 2016-01-14**:
Maybe SetLinearVel has been changed "to refer to setting the velocity state (like an initial condition), but not turning on a persistent motor controller" like SetVelocity has, according to this answer:

http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8371/kobukiturtlebot-doesnt-move-when-given-velocity-commands-in-gazebo-5/?answer=8377#post-id-8377

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

To answer the first question, the box turns over because of friction coefficient, which has a default value of 1.  Update your collision to below to prevent rolling:

```
    <collision name="collision">
      <geometry>
        <box>
          <size>1 1 1</size>
        </box>
      </geometry>
      <surface>
        <friction>
          <ode>
            <mu>0</mu>
            <mu2>0</mu2>
          </ode>
        </friction>
      </surface>
    </collision>
```

And remember, even though the tutorial moves the block with `Model::SetLinearVel`, which forces CG's linear motion in a straight line, physics dictates that there is still a downward gravity force, and there is still an upward normal contact force and its corresponding tangential friction forces. Ultimately, the combination of forces imparts a rolling moment about CG of the box, causing it to tumble.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) with karma: 1873 on 2016-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I can't help with you first question, but I can hopefully point you to some useful resources.

First off, the entire gazebo API is documented [here](https://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/gazebo/api/dev/index.html)

With particularly interesting sections on [link](https://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/gazebo/api/dev/classgazebo_1_1physics_1_1Link.html) and [joints](https://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/gazebo/api/dev/classgazebo_1_1physics_1_1Joint.html), which are all within  [physics](https://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/gazebo/api/dev/group__gazebo__physics.html)

I find that learning by example works well... all of the gazebo plugins are [here](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/default/plugins/), and some simple ones I've written can be found [here](https://github.com/PeterMitrano/allwpilib/tree/master/simulation/frc_gazebo_plugins)

Hopefully that should get you started! If you have specific ideas on tutorials/information that isn't well documented, help contribute to the documentation! We write our tutorials in markdown, so just make a pull request [this repository](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo_tutorials) if you have something to add.

---

Originally posted by [Peter Mitrano](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1068/peter-mitrano/) with karma: 768 on 2016-01-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [raequin](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2401/raequin/) on 2016-01-15**:
I'd been wanting some examples and reading the gazebo plugins did not occur to me.  Thanks also for linking to your plugins.  They are at a good level of difficulty for me to learn from: some stuff I know already and some stuff I'll have to research.

I still would like to understand why the velocity of the model origin in the tutorial is different from what's passed to SetLinearVelocity.